# Extjs Combo Box Saving Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, combobox

Having an issue with Extjs (6.0.1) Combo box. 
Basically, we have two ways change data: Selecting multiple rows and changing the combo values all at once, two: Changing one combo box and press save.

However, to save the state of the store, both methods use the same 'save' button. The problem we are having is that after changing one combo box value and saving it, about ~30 seconds after the following error occurs:

```
'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': parameter 1 
is not of type 'Node'.'
```

The code for saving the state of the store is below:

```
setValue: function(record) {
        this.checkboxPaging.clearPersistedSelection();
        if (record) {
            this.store.getProxy().extraParams.id = record.get('Id');
            this.storeStateManager.reset();
            this.store.load();
        } else {
            this.store.removeAll();
        }

    },
```

Any guidance/help with the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why did you tag `reactjs`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention we are also using React. Mostly added the tag incase there were any issues between the two

Comment: Does this error affects anything on UI or in request while saving ?